# pass ajax array into data:

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

so i'm new to ajax and i'm facing a problem getting all the values from my form.

So i wanna insert the name reply_txt and the $ newsId to my table

html form:

```
<form>
   <input type="hidden" name="replyToPost" value="<?php echo $newsId;?>">
   <textarea name="reply_txt" class="replyText"></textarea>
   <button class="replySubmit">Answer</button> 
</form>
```

ajax: Ithink i have to pass an array in somehow into the data:replyData

```
$(".replySubmit").click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();//prevent action from button

        var replyData = 'reply_txt='+ $(".replyText").val(); //build a post data structure

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST", // POST type
            url: "response.php", //call ajax on page
            dataType:"text", //type of data html/ajax/jason ...
            data:replyData, //Form variables intups

            success:function(response){
                $(".respondsReply").append(response);
                $(".replyText").val(''); //empty text field on successful
            },
            error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
                alert(thrownError);
            }
        });
});
```

response.php: The error is undefined variable $newsId

```
if(isset($_POST["reply_txt"]) && strlen($_POST["reply_txt"])>0){
   $replyToSave = filter_var($_POST["reply_txt"],FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_HIGH);
   $newsId = $_POST["replyToPost"]; 

$userId = $_SESSION['userId'];
$reply_row = $db->query("INSERT INTO replyPost(message,newsId_fk,userId_fk) VALUES('$replyToSave','$newsId','$userId')");
}
```

Comment: you not each out anything in php

Comment: each out? what? i just wanna insert it to my table but i need it in the data: i think

Comment: sorry I was programming with .each() so I got confused with that .. I mean echo out .. you should echo out something in php to get response in success function

Comment: try what i tell in answer, and check once. thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can actually pass a JS object to the `data` attribute of the ajax call:

```
$(".replySubmit").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();//prevent action from button

    // Build the data object for ajax request:
    var replyData = {
      "reply_txt" : $(".replyText").val(),
      "replyToPost": $("input[name=replyToPost]").val()
    };

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST", // POST type
        url: "response.php", //call ajax on page
        dataType: "text", //type of data html/ajax/jason ...
        data: replyData, //data object

        success: function(response){
            $(".respondsReply").append(response);
            $(".replyText").val(''); //empty text field on successful
        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
            alert(thrownError);
        }
    });
});
```

---

Also I hope that the code in `response.php` is only for demonstration/testing!
Using un-escaped $_POST values in the SQL statement is EXTREMLY dangerous

Comment: thanks, i'm going to try that.and yes it's only testing at the moment. when it works i'll change it to PDO as the rest of my code for the project

Answer (score 2):

You are only sending the `reply_txt` value in the AJAX data. You need to add the `replyToPost` field's value too:

```
var replyData = 'reply_txt=' + $(".replyText").val() + '&replyToPost=' + $('input[name="replyToPost"]').val();
```

Alternatively (and preferably) you can use the `serialize()` to let jQuery automatically create a serialised string for you:

```
$(".replySubmit").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault(); //prevent action from button
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST", // POST type
        url: "response.php", //call ajax on page
        dataType: "text", //type of data html/ajax/jason ...
        data: $(this).serialize(), //Form variables intups
        success:function(response){
            $(".respondsReply").append(response);
            $(".replyText").val(''); //empty text field on successful
        },
        error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
            alert(thrownError);
        }
    });
});
```